# What the determination for this depending changing?

Tags: meaning, definition, word-meaning

**Conjugation is:**

put - put - put

eat - ate - eaten

run - ran - run

**Question:**

> What the name for this depending between subject and verb:

subject (he, she, it) = verb (eats)

subject (we, you, they, I) = verb (eat)

subject (he, she, it) = verb (is)

subject (we, you, they) = verb (are)

my guess: the process of depending between subject and verb is a **declension**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Declension* is a term borrowed from Latin grammar designating morphological variation in nouns and adjectives, just as *conjugation* (also borrowed from Latin) designates morphological variation in verbs.

The interaction within a specific syntactic context between the forms taken by words of different classes—for instance, the requirement in English that a the form of a finite verb is governed by the number and person of its subject—is called [*agreement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_(linguistics)) or *concord*.

Answer (score 2):

You **conjugate** a verb, so that it agrees with its subject. (You choose the correct **conjugation**).

You **decline** a noun, so that it agrees with its role in the sentence. (You choose the correct **declension**).